# Deploying an MVC5 ASP.net application from VS 2013 to local IIS get - "an unkown error occurred" bullet on the login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I created a ASP.NET MVC 5 Web application using the SPA template in Visual Studio 2013, Ultimate edition.

The only modification I made was to the connection string where I point to the localhost instance of sqlserver. I also changed the initial catalog name.

When I run the application against the IISExpress - everything works fine and I can login and register new users.

However when I publish the very same application to my local IIS , I get the login page and the error bullet says .an unknown error occurred.

I am not sure what the error implies and am lost as to how to debug the issue. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<connectionStrings>
```

-->

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Identity;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Connection:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Identity;User Id=sa;Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**sa** is Sql Server Username and **123** is Password

Comment: This works as long as I use the MVC template. It does not work with the SPA template.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on Web folder(IIS_IUSRS), check app pool identity etc. The connection string should still work, it's a SQL call made on same box so nothing should fail unless the identity calling the SQL SERVER is changed from a user that is allowed access to one that does not (App Pool different from IISEXPRESS possible).  It is possible the other answer is the fix only if the sa username is sa and pass is 123.